# SQL Server: Stored proc can execute well but at the end error "Cannot find the object"

Tags: sql, sql-server

all:

I've searched for a couple of hours now regarding problem I get. There are similar questions on Google and here, but none is same.

I have a simple stored procedure A, EXECUTE permission is correctly granted to my login. It basically populates some table with data. It is in same schema as my login user. I can EXECUTE it successfully, which means all data are populated expectedly. However, at the end of execution, the message window shows:

**Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Procedure A, Line xxx
Cannot find the object 'A', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

The line number points to end of SP definition. I have no idea why this error message comes up and the SP seems no problem at all in terms of execution result.

EDIT:

The SP code is like below:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SysObjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.spA') AND type = 'P')
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.spA
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spA
    @ReportCCY as char(3) = 'GBP',
    @Date as date = null                  /* for regression testing */
AS
BEGIN

    if (@Date is null)
        select @Date = convert(varchar(20), max(VDate), 112) from JB H (nolock)

    declare @dbname as varchar(50)
    select @dbname = DB_NAME()
    exec DBA_admin.App.p_usr_Truncate @DB=@dbname, @Schema='dbo', @Table='ATable'

    insert into dbo.ATable
    select r.Value, I.id
    from Rates r
    join Inst I (nolock) on I.idCCyBase = r.idHold and r.ccyinto = @ReportCcy and r.dtDate = @Date
END

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.spA TO UserGrp
GO
```

Comment: Can you paste the procedure code?

Comment: I wish I could paste full code, but not convenient. However I can state facts: 1) The SP code only does TRUNCATE table, and INSERT SELECT, nothing else; 2) The SP works fine without this annoying message when run under a super user account, but not this one. Though I have no idea why SP runs from beginning to end without error but pops up this seemingly 'hollow' error message.

Comment: please paste at least the line of code where you assume something's wrong

Comment: Problem is there is no such thing as 'the line of code where you assume something's wrong'. INSERT is last statement which does the work, next is 'END' of the SP.

Comment: And, the INSERT, which is last statement in SP, also output line count it inserted, proving it is successful.

Comment: What sort of permissions does the account you are using have? Is the procedure running on multiple databases? Additionally posting the sproc will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot 'GO' after 'END'. Now 'GRANT EXECUTE' is a part of your procedure.